# Automatic login

Tags: ios, objective-c, simperium

I am looking for a way to load simperium without having to present the login view after the first time the user enters his info.

This is what I get if I dont log in after the first time:

> Simperium error: bucket list not loaded. Ensure Simperium is started
>   before any objects are fetched.

This is what I use to init Simperium:

```
self.simperium = [[Simperium alloc] initWithRootViewController:
                                    _window.rootViewController];
```

thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this error?

Comment: I assume this is for OSX given your use of `_window`? Is the problem that you're seeing an authentication screen even after you sign in for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using OAuth.

OAuth is a system where the user can provide their credentials for a popular service like Google, Twitter, Facebook or other open ID providers.

Rather than caching the credentials on the device, which would be insecure, since getting access to these would give the user access to a large number of systems, OAuth gets the main authentication service to provide a token.

This token gets stored on the device and can be used to login automatically the next time.

The drawback is that it can be quite tricky to set up the first time, since there's quite a lot of complexity going on, not to mention that the standard is quite new so there was some evolution in the specification.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with Simperium. Am I missing something?

Comment: OAuth is a way to authenticate a user "without having to present the login view after the first time the user enters his info" . . its not specific to simperium.

Comment: Okay. I assume the OP is using the iOS Framework for Simperium, which is handling the login, so switching to OAuth isn't really an option.

Comment: Ok, I must've misunderstood. I thought the authentication could be treated as a separate concern. . . if its too tightly integrated then perhaps Simperium need to provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Simperium just needs user credentials to get started (the app id and username/token). The login view is a convenience to get those credentials for you, if you can already obtain them using some other means (like using HTTP auth API: https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#auth) then you can directly supply those without using the login view. See methods in https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/blob/develop/Simperium/SPAuthenticator.m